# Parameters to helpers used in inclusion template tags?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'd like to be able to call (global) template helpers from inclusion template tags.

So this works;
Static version:

```
{{>volcanoTable pagination=5)}}
```

But i'd like to get the value of pagination per user by using Template helper function named getPref(key,defaultvalue).

"Dynamic version":

```
{{>volcanoTable pagination=getPref("pagination",5) }}
```

which gives error: 
 Expected space
   ...ue pagination=getPref('a',5) )}}

Also tried different versions, but they didn't work either;

like `{{>volcanoTable pagination=getPref "pagination" "5" }}`

Or is there another way to get the same desired results?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a helper which returns a context object. For example:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  myPagination: function(n) {
    // extract the default pagination for the user
    var pagination = Meteor.user().profile.pagination;
    if (pagination) {
      return {pagination: pagination};
    } else {
      return {pagination: n};
    }
  }
});
```

Which you can use like this:

```html
<template name='myTemplate'>
  {{> volcanoTable myPagination 6}}
</template>
```

In this case, the `volcanoTable` would get a context of `{pagination: 6}` only if there was no default pagination property for the user. Of course you could make `myPagination` a global helper if it's useful outside of this template.